# Three columns with equal width and four columns with minimum width

Tags: html, css

I have four columns on a page which contain arrows pointing left or right. I wish to size these columns so that they are only as wide as the arrow they contain. However, I wish for the remaining three columns("col-1", "col-2" and "col-3") to remain equally wide irrespective of what data they contain.

```
<div class="divsholder">
  <div id="col-1" class="column"></div>
  <div id="right-1" class="mini-column"></div>
  <div id="left-1" class="mini-column"></div>
  <div id="col-2" class="column"></div>
  <div id="right-2" class="mini-column"></div>
  <div id="left-2" class="mini-column"></div>
  <div id="col-3" class="column"></div>
</div>
```

"right-1", "right-2", "left-1" and "left-2" are the columns I wish to keep at a minimum width.

http://jsfiddle.net/barra/121v4ow8/171/

What css will achieve this for me?

Answer (score 0):

Change your css into this and it will work fine, hope it helps!

```js
let a = ["l", "e", "f", "t"];
let b = ["r", "i", "g", "h", "t"];
let c = ["n", "e", "w"];
a.sort();
b.sort();
c.sort();

let draw_column = (id, data, func) => {
    data.forEach((n, i) => $('#' + id).append(
        $('<div/>', {
            'text': n,
            'id': id + '-' + i
        }).on({
            'click': () => func(i)
        })
    ))
}

let redraw_column = (id, data, func) => {
    $("#" + id).empty(),
        draw_column(id, data, func)
};

let move_data = (data1, data2, i) => {
        data2.push(
                data1.splice(i, 1)
        ),
        data1.sort(),
        data2.sort()
}

let left_data = (l) => {
        return Array(l).fill('<');
}

let right_data = (l) => {
        return Array(l).fill('>');
}

let move = (data1, data2, i) => {
        move_data(data1,data2,i),
        redraw_column("col-1", a, i => {}),
        redraw_column("right-1",right_data(a.length),i=>move(a, b, i)),
        redraw_column("left-1",left_data(b.length),i=>move(b, a, i)),
        redraw_column("col-2", b, i, i => {}),
        redraw_column("right-2",right_data(b.length),i=>move(b, c, i)),
        redraw_column("left-2",left_data(c.length),i=>move(c, b, i)),
        redraw_column("col-3", c, i, i => {})
}

draw_column("col-1", a, i => {});
draw_column("right-1", right_data(a.length), i => move(a, b, i));
draw_column("left-1", left_data(b.length), i => move(b, a, i));
draw_column("col-2", b, i => {});
draw_column("right-2", right_data(b.length), i => move(b, c, i));
draw_column("left-2", left_data(c.length), i => move(c, b, i));
draw_column("col-3", c, i => {});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box
}

html, body {
    width: 100%
}

.divsholder {
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

div {
    border: 1px dashed red;
    margin: 5px;
}

.column {
    flex: 1;
}

.mini-column {
    flex: 0;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divsholder">
    <div id="col-1" class="column"></div>
    <div id="right-1" class="mini-column"></div>
    <div id="left-1" class="mini-column"></div>
    <div id="col-2" class="column"></div>
    <div id="right-2" class="mini-column"></div>
    <div id="left-2" class="mini-column"></div>
    <div id="col-3" class="column"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: when adding snippet consider adding a full code, or simple put code

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks for reminding, it is a bit lengthy so I choose to post CSS only just now, post updated

Comment: You can put the code you changed in your answer then add a snippet  with full in collapsed mode, it won't take too much space ;)